# Cpu spikes with Jquery datatables 10+ and IE8?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-8, datatables

Currently our client environment still uses IE 8 and we have CPU spikes with Jquery datatable in this browser? I read articles that setting a fixed height helps. Any other recommendations? Help with speed?

-- Using MVC4 and web api.

Comment: Unfortunately this is far too broad, with far too little context/data.

Comment: agree with @JonathanSampson.  I have seen people solving this known issue with IE by overriding the `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` functions, but never tried it myself.